# Using Prefixes and Suffixes in Hunspell

Tags: hunspell

How can Hunspell take into account the incorrect combination of some prefixes and suffixes?

Let's say the **aff file** contains:

**PFX P Y 2
PFX P 0 la
PFX P 0 ma**

**SFX A Y 1
SFX A 0 zon**

And in the **dic file** there is:
**adal/PA**

So Hunspell will generate the following values:
*adal
adalzon
laadalzon
laadal
maadalzon
maadal*

But I need it to be incorrect for the word "adal" to simultaneously combine it with both a prefix and a suffix.

That is, it is correct:
*adal
adalzon
laadal
maadal*

Incorrect:
*laadalzon
maadalzon*

Please tell me. How can you make sure that incorrect options are excluded.